# PHP isset for a submit form didn't return any value

Tags: php, html, forms, post, isset

By following some example on the internet I managed to make a form to insert user.

I used isset for the submit function. When the form is completely filled and submit, the result will be echo to show the status message. Unfortunately, the form didn't work at all and when submit button is clicked, the form is reset.

Since I use stored procedure, both of the `ReturnStatus` and `ReturnMessage` will be automatically called according to the input value from the form.

Here's the code.

```
<?php
include "config.php";
if(isset($_POST['sub']))
{

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

error_reporting(-1);

$RegType="D";
$UserId=$_POST["UserId"];
$UserPwd=$_POST["UserPwd"];
$UserNm=$_POST["UserNm"];

$stmt=odbc_exec($conn,"CALL UserInsert ('".$RegType."','UserId','UserPwd','UserNm')");

if (!$stmt) {
"Error : " . odbc_errormsg();
}

if (odbc_fetch_row($stmt)) {
$ReturnStatus=odbc_result($stmt,'ReturnStatus');
$ReturnMessage=odbc_result($stmt,'ReturnMessage');
}

if($ReturnStatus==1) {
echo $ReturnMessage=odbc_result($stmt,'ReturnMessage');
}        
}  
?>

<table>
<form class="form"  method="post">

<tr>
<td class = "nama">Nama Pengguna<span class="required">&nbsp; * &nbsp;</span></td>
<td><input type="text" name="UserNm" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class = "userid">Id Pengguna<span class="required">&nbsp; * &nbsp;</span></td>
<td><input type="text" name="UserId" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class = "password">Kata Laluan<span class="required">&nbsp; * &nbsp;</span></td>
<td><input type="password" name="UserPwd" value=""></td>
</tr>

<tr><td>
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</td></tr>
</table>
```

I'm sure I miss something. Please guide me. Thank you.

**UPDATED**

Fixed the following :

```
- Fix the name of the button
- PHP error reporting
- Isset
```

Comment: You need to set `name` property as `submit` in submit button

Comment: Add a name to your button, you're checking for a POST named `submit`, but there is no element named `submit` in your form

Comment: there are two solutions, `1 - add name attribute for button input` or `2 - use if(count($_POST) > 0)`

Comment: Errors, why are you using `<form>` inside the isset check?

Comment: A careless mistake of mine. After added the `name` of the button, the form is directed to a blank page.

Comment: I'm following some example from the internet. They work just fine. Where should I use the `<form>` then? @devpro

Comment: This line `$UserId=$_POST["UserId"];` is supposed to get the value of this input `<input type="text" name="UserID" value="">`. It doesn't do it because `"UserId" != "UserID"`

Comment: @axiac: yes you are right, :)

Comment: You have ruined some of the advice in the accepted answer by adding the name attribute to your posted snippet.  Do not wreck your question, it will confuse future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Few Important Suggestions:**

***First*** of all enable [`PHP error reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) in your code, this will help you find actual errors:

```
// Same as error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

// Report all PHP errors
error_reporting(-1);
```

***Second***, don't know why are you using `<form></form>` inside the `isset()` check, this will return nothing on page refresh.

***Third***, very important, as everyone mentioned in answers, you are missing the name attribute in button input.

```
<input type="submit" value="Simpan" name="submit">
```

***Fourth***, for suppose, if you fixed this error, you will get the undefined variable in failure case for `$ReturnStatus`. You must need to define as 0 at top level declaration because if `odbc_fetch_row($stmt)` failed this will return the `Undefined Variable Warnings`

Comment: Thank you @devpro . I fixed my code according to your answer. Can you tell me more on the _define as 0 at top level declaration_ ?

Comment: @Mint: just replace `if($ReturnStatus==1) {` with `if(isset($ReturnStatus) && $ReturnStatus==1) {`

Comment: I still have these as the error  `odbc_fetch_row(): supplied argument is not a valid ODBC result resource` @devpro

Comment: Alright, I managed to get rid of the error. Thank you for your time :) @devpro

Answer (score 0):

please change

```
<input type="submit" value="Simpan"> // you are not added name attribute here
```

to

```
<input type="submit" value="Simpan" name="submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following line:

```
<input type="submit" value="Simpan">
```

and you are trying to access it by:

```
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
```

here you forget to add `name="submit"` in input so make it like:

```
<input type="submit" value="Simpan" name="submit">
```

**Explanation"** `$_POST['index']` here `index` is the name of tag

Answer (score 0):

If you add `name` attribute in `input` type `submit` then I hope your code will work.
So in html edit:

```
<input type="submit" value="Simpan">
```

as

```
<input type="submit" name='submit' value="Simpan">
```

Answer (score 0):

i fixed some errors and its working fine

```
<table>
<form class="form"  method="post">

<tr><td class = "nama">Name : <span class="required">&nbsp; * &nbsp;</span></td>
<td><input type="text" name="UserNm" value=""></td></tr>

<tr><td class = "userid">Id : <span class="required">&nbsp; * &nbsp;</span></td>
<td><input type="text" name="UserID" value=""></td></tr>

<tr><td>
<input type="submit" value="Simpan" name="submit">
</td></tr>

</form>
</table>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$RegType="D";
$UserId=$_POST["UserID"];
$UserNm=$_POST["UserNm"];
echo $UserId;
echo $UserNm;
$stmt=odbc_exec($conn,"CALL UserInsert ('".$RegType."','UserId','UserNm')");

if (!$stmt) {
"Error : " . odbc_errormsg();
}

if (odbc_fetch_row($stmt)) {
$ReturnStatus=odbc_result($stmt,'ReturnStatus');
$ReturnMessage=odbc_result($stmt,'ReturnMessage');
}

if($ReturnStatus==1) {
echo $ReturnMessage=odbc_result($stmt,'ReturnMessage');
} 

}   
?>
```

Comment: Would be very helpful to the OP if you said what you had fixed

Answer (score 0):

Use name="submit" on your submit button

Then the post car can be accessed